# Sidebars in chaos - How do I align a sidebar to the top navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, blogger

I am attempting to align a sidebar to the top navbar into blogger. I'm sure I'm missing some incredibly simple tag so that the sidebar and body are adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

First,

move the leftbar div above the home div. Then, add the following css

```
#header {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#primary_nav {
    clear: both;
}

#leftbar {
    margin-top: 52px;
}

#single, #home {
    width: 480px;
    float: left;
}

#central_column {
    margin-left:0;
}

#rightbar {
    margin-top: 52px;
}
```

Also remove the clearboth divs after home div.

Answer (score 0):

1. Move leftbar div on top of home
2. Add float:left to leftbar,home and rightbar
3. Add top margins to leftbar, home and right bar
4. remove clearboth divs, after home div

Answer (score 0):

Here is your page layout

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sidebar {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.content {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
}
.navbar {
    height: 50px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.main {
    height: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<aside class="sidebar">Sidebar</aside>
<div class="content">
 <nav class="navbar">Navbar</nav>
 <div class="main">Main</div>
</div>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```